# Write a program to check the number of the same characters of a given string for every ASCII value

Tags: c

I am getting `a` to `z` counts but I want their count too: `(`, `"`, `-`, `,`...

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int letter_counter(char* str, char c)
{
    int i,counter=0;

    for(i=0;str[i]!= 0;i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == c)
            counter++;
    }
    
    return counter;
}
    
int main()
{
    char str[] ="Write a function that takes a character and a string, and returns the index of that character in the string (or -1 if the character is not found)";
    
    char c;
    for(c = 'a';c<='z';c++) 
    {
        printf(" %c --- %d\n",c,letter_counter(str,c));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 a --- 14
 b --- 0
 c --- 7
 d --- 4
 e --- 10
 f --- 4
 g --- 2
 h --- 8
 i --- 8
 j --- 0
 k --- 1
 l --- 0
 m --- 0
 n --- 11
 o --- 5
 p --- 0
 q --- 0
 r --- 12
 s --- 5
 t --- 17
 u --- 3
 v --- 0
 w --- 0
 x --- 1
 y --- 0
 z --- 0
```

Comment: The function `letter_counter` already works in such a way that this is possible (so the name is a bit misleading, `char_counter` may be better). You just have to check the rest outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

I've just basically changed your for loop to not only go from `'a'` to `'z'` but from ASCII 32 (space) to ASCII 127 (you can check an ASCII table here, for example: https://theascii.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Basic-ASCII-table-image.png). Notice this will just work for plain text, using ASCII values below 128 (e.g. not for Unicode).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int letter_counter(char* str, char c)
{
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; str[i] != 0; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] == c)
        {
           counter++;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}

int main()
{
   char str[] = "Write a function that takes a character and a string,"
                " and returns the index of that character in the string "
                " (or -1 if the character is not found)";

    for (char c = 32; c < 127; ++c)
    {
        int count = letter_counter(str, c);
        if (count)
        {
            printf(" %c --- %d\n", c, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/6TqvnMrqh

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    char* text = "Write a program to check the number of the same characters of a given string for every ASCII value getting a to z counts but I want their count too: (, \", -, ,...";
    size_t count[CHAR_MAX] = {0};
    
    while(*text)
    {
        count[*text++]++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<CHAR_MAX; ++i)
    {
        if (count[i])
        {
            printf("%c : %d\n", i, count[i] );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```